# java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming, android-fullscreen

I'm trying to play a video using FullscreenVideoView but i keep getting this error everytime that i try to play a stored video

```
Java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.

 File n  = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/Downloads/video9.mp4");
        Log.e(TAG, "URL:" + n); 

        fullscreenVideoView.videoFile(n).enableAutoStart().fastForwardSeconds(5)
                .rewindSeconds(5)
                .addSeekBackwardButton()
                .addSeekForwardButton();
```

Comment: Try with `videoFile(n.getAbsolutePath())`

Comment: @DineshShingadiya same error :/

Comment: the exception should generated in fullscreenVideoView. so kindly post codes of the fullscreenVideoView.

Comment: @Ifta that the full code for fullscreenvideoview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bunch of reasons, why your dataSource doesn't work.
Try to add logging:

```
 File n  = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/Downloads/video9.mp4");
        Log.e(TAG, "URL:" + n); 
        Log.e(TAG, "exists: " + n.exists());

        fullscreenVideoView.videoFile(n).enableAutoStart().fastForwardSeconds(5)
                .rewindSeconds(5)
                .addSeekBackwardButton()
                .addSeekForwardButton();
```

Probably file doesn't exist. It may be because of not granted permissions or the wrong way of file.

At first I would advise you ti check permissions. If you running your code on app on 6+ android, you must request permissions in runtime. In your case they would be: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: you are right the file does't exist.....so i moved the file into my raw folder and still getting the same error exist false; 
File n  = new File("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.vid);